# Change Navbar Size in Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm somewhat new to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Right now I'm working with Bootstrap, and I inserted a logo into the navbar, resulting in overflow. The navbar did not resize with the logo, so part of the logo is sticking out onto the page.

I would like to know how to resize the navbar to fit with the logo.

Edit: Here is some HTML code. The CSS code was too long to put in here, and I have no idea where the CSS code snippets for this part of the code are.
Here is a link to the CSS: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwHwbNKvGsEpbmxvUTVpcUNkZjg/view?usp=sharing

```
        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://www.mexicobariatricsurgerycenters.com/images/logo.png" height="70px" title="Logo" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container theme-showcase">
```

Thanks for the help so far! This is my first question on here, sorry if I'm a bit vague with my asking.

Comment: Would be happy to help you. Your question will get more attention and better answers if you adhere to [question guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: post the code of what you've attempted and we'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use Bootstrap with .less you could update the variables.less file and simply change the height variable seen below:

```
@navbar-height: 50px;
```

But I think you are probably using standard CSS, in which case you would have to override it like so:

```
.navbar { 
  min-height: 50px; // your value here. 
}
```

Keeping in mind you would need to do this after the bootstrap CSS is included, and your selector may need to be more specific.

Also, if you have put the logo in the .brand portion of it, you may also need to extend that using something like

```
.navbar-brand { 
  padding: 15px 15px; // your values
  height: 50px; // your value
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I found the variable in the CSS document and changed it, and that fixed the problem. Now to resize the navbar buttons to fit...

Comment: @julky117 if my answer helped you please mark it appropriately. thx

Answer (score 0):

Why u wanna resize the navbar.. try resizing the logo instead

Anyways, if you wanna hide some content thats overflowing you could use css property:

```
overflow:hidden
```